# Скролл во вкладках

Tags: css3, jquery, javascript, ui, html5

Есть код:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>

    <title>Закладки на чистом CSS</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>

    <style>
    .tabs {
      position: relative;   
      min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
      clear: both;
      margin: 25px 0;
    }
    .tab {
      float: left;
    }
    .tab label {
      background: #eee; 
      padding: 10px; 
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 
      margin-left: -1px; 
      position: relative;
      left: 1px; 
    }
    .tab [type=radio] {
      display: none;   
    }
    .content {
      position: absolute;
      top: 28px;
      left: 0;
      background: white;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc; 

      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .content > * {
      opacity: 0;

      -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      -moz-transform:    translateX(-100%);
      -ms-transform:     translateX(-100%);
      -o-transform:      translateX(-100%);

      -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
      -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
      -ms-transition:     all 0.6s ease;
      -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
    }   
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label {
      background: white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      z-index: 2;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
      z-index: 1;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content > * {
      opacity: 1;

      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      -moz-transform:    translateX(0);
      -ms-transform:     translateX(0);
      -o-transform:      translateX(0);
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">

    <div class="tabs">

       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
           <label for="tab-1">Закладка №1</label>

           <div class="content">
               <p>Содержание закладки №1</p>
           </div> 
       </div>

       <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-2">Закладка №2</label>

           <div class="content">
               <div class="dropp"> 
     <div id="element1"  class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/1.png"  /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element2" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/2.png" width="250" height="140" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element3" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/3.png" width="249" height="31" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element4" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/4.png" width="250" height="143" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element5" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/5.png" width="551" height="245" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element6" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/6.png" width="250" height="140" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element7" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/7.png" width="94" height="19" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element8" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/8.png" width="151" height="19" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element9" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/9.png" width="112" height="19" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element10" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/10.png" width="169" height="19" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element11" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/11.png" width="81" height="31" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element12" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/12.png" width="171" height="164" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element13" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/13.png" width="171" height="165" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element14" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/14.png" width="22" height="150" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element15" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/15.png" width="100" height="32" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element16" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/16.png" width="100" height="32" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element17" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/17.png" width="100" height="31" /><div class="resaze"></div></div>
      <div id="element18" class="img"><div class="delete"></div><img src="img/18.png" width="100" height="31" /><div class="resaze"></div></div> 
    </div>
           </div> 
       </div>

        <div class="tab">
           <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
           <label for="tab-3">Закладка №3</label>

           <div class="content">
               <p>Содержание закладки №3</p>

               <img src="http://placedog.com/200/100">
           </div> 
       </div>

    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Как в каждой закладке сделать скролл по иксу? (т.к. предполагается наполнить их некоторым количеством изображений), а так же необходимо чтобы они прокручивались для просмотра.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/qqQbM/

в чем проблема не понимаю.

```
.content {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Извиняюсь - в transitions и css не силен, но у вас все картинки в закладках .tab будут в одной куче похоже. Потому что имеют одинаковый отступ справа и position : absolute

Comment: там он их перекрывает с помошью z-index (странный конечно вариант)